# Why do these methods recurse infinitely?

Tags: c#, recursion, methods, void

I've been working on a program that creates Rational numbers, and when I call any of these methods I get a stack overflow from recursion.

```
public Rational(){
      new Rational(0,1);
}
public Rational(int n){
      new Rational(n,1);
}
public Rational(int numerator, int denominator){
      new Rational(numerator,denominator);
}
```

Can someone explain to me why these methods infinitely recurse?

Comment: Because your constructor tries to create a new object, which then creates another object, which ....

Comment: First there is no math.  Don't you want numerator/denominator?  When do you stop?  You are calling new Rational(numerator,denominator); over and over and over again.

Comment: Also that is definitely not how you delegate constructor calls, where did you learn to write the constructor like this?

Answer (score 0):

These aren't just any methods, these are constructors and calling them in a recursive manner like this is almost certainly not what you intend. Eg. when you call the first constructor, it creates two new objects (`this` plus the new Rational in the body of the constructor, which calls another, which calls another...)

To answer your question: When your third constructor runs, it calls itself. There is no base case to end the recursion, so it will recurse until stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rational(int numerator, int denominator){
      new Rational(numerator,denominator);
}
```

This constructor calls itself with the arguments it's given. Unless I'm missing something(C# is not a language I'm terribly familiar with), you never get to a point where you exit the functions, you just keep spawning more & more `Rational`s. Your constructors should probably look something like.

```
public Rational(){
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 1;
}
public Rational(int n){
    numerator = n;
    denominator = 1;
}
public Rational(int n, int d){
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if the first two constructors chained to the third...

Answer (score 0):

`new` will create a new instance, it will not continue initializing the current object. So you have a recursive call where the constructor creates a new instance, which creates a new instance etc.

I think what you are looking for is this:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp18
{
    public class Rational
    {
        // A
        public Rational() : this(0, 1) // Calls C
        {
        }

        // B
        public Rational(int n) : this(n, 1) // Calls C
        {
        }

        // C
        public Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
        {
            // Init here
        }
    }
}
```

Which could be also be chained like this:

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp18
{
    public class Rational
    {
        // A
        public Rational() : this(0) // Calls B
        {
        }

        // B
        public Rational(int n) : this(n, 1) // Calls C
        {
        }

        // C
        public Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
        {
            // Init here
        }
    }
}
```